# How to compare dates in C# without using time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a C# function, but it didn't function the way I had hoped. It should return result 1, but it is returning result 2, today, 06-10-2023. It's my code here.

```
using System.Globalization;

int value = GetFeesType();

Console.WriteLine("FeesType =  {0}", value);

int GetFeesType()
{
    int FeesType = 1;

    DateTime TodayDate = DateTime.Now;

    DateTime FeesType1 = DateTime.ParseExact("06-10-2023", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
    DateTime FeesType2 = DateTime.ParseExact("27-10-2023", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
    DateTime FeesType3 = DateTime.ParseExact("16-11-2023", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
    DateTime FeesType4 = DateTime.ParseExact("01-12-2023", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);

    if (TodayDate <= FeesType1)
    {
        FeesType = 1;
    }
    else if (TodayDate <= FeesType2)
    {
        FeesType = 2;
    }
    else if (TodayDate <= FeesType3)
    {
        FeesType = 3;
    }
    else if (TodayDate <= FeesType4 || TodayDate > FeesType4)
    {
        FeesType = 4;
    }

    return FeesType;
}
```

How do you fix it?

Comment: What was the value of DateTime.Now at that time?

Comment: Also this `else if (TodayDate <= FeesType4 || TodayDate > FeesType4)` does not make sense. You could as well remove that condition. It is always true.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` returns date with time. Assume now is "2023-10-06T14:24:00.000Z", this will definitely greater than "06-10-2023". If you want compare date only, you should use `TodayDate.Date` or `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: @YongShun then what I do ?

Comment: @YongShun, Thanks Now I can understand, it is fixed now with TodayDate.Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FeesType1` is `2023-10-06T00:00:00.000`
`TodayDate` was `2023-10-06T<something greater than 00:00:00>`

hence `TodayDate <= FeesType1` is in fact `false`.

If you do not care for the exact time, switch to using `DateOnly` or use `DateTime.Date` and the behavior should be correct.